# разборка строки

Tags: строки

есть дана строка следующего вида : [ ( A B ) [ C A ] ]

неоходимо, что находиться в кргулых скобках сложить, а то что находиться в квадратных - умножить, тоесть: A+B *(C*A)

Comment: Ну делайте, коли надо. Стек в руки, и вперёд. В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Даже язык в тегах не указали